# Fix for "this webpage is not available"

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I have a Lenovo 230. I run chrome but I get similar responses on all browsers. I've taken off any junk programs and cleaned up every thing I can think of and tried everything I can find online, including but not limited to clearing history, checking chrome settings, netsh, cache clearing, proxy check, ipconfig, dns reset, etc. Any other ideas out there.

Comment: This question is really hard to answer  - it's just too broad. However, can you try visiting both https and http sites, and also try with another browser. Also, what Operating System is this?  Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/847455/edit) and include this information (or else it will probably be shut down)

Comment: Please add a tag for the OS you have (I assume Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You can check step-by-step: start `cmd.exe`, the rest is to be entered there. I'll assume you are connected to your home network, not to a corporate network.

1. Check that your network is up and running: `ipconfig` should show your network connection. If there is a hint that the network is disconnected, then either WLAN is not connected or your LAN cable is unplugged.
2. Check your IP configuration: `ipconfig /all` should list your IP address, an IP address for the gateway and one or two IP addresses for DNS server(s). Your IP address should not be a 169.254.x.x. If you don't get an IP address you might have WLAN connectivity/stability problems or a problem with your router or you might have configured static IP and might better have used DHCP.
3. Check local IP connectivity: `ping xxx` where you replace xxx with the IP address of the gateway you read it in step 2. You should get 4 lines with ping replies and their timings. If not, the IP connectivity to your router might be broken. You should still continue with step 4 because a lot of devices do not answer to pings.
4. Check that DNS is working: `nslookup www.superuser.com` should give you the IP address of the superuser web server. If you don't get the IP, then your DNS has trouble.
5. Check global IP connectivity: `ping www.superuser.com` should print 4 lines with ping replies and their timings. If not, then your internet connection has trouble.
6. Check browser: open `www.superuser.com` in your browser. If steps 1-5 showed no problem, you should not see problems here. If you cannot open the web page, then your browser might be misconfigured. Check that you don't have a proxy configured.